# Change FontSize in App resource from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, wpf-style

For a WPF TextBox control, I set the FontSize using a XAML style in my app.xaml like this:

```
<System:Double x:Key="FontSizeVal">12</System:Double>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource FontSizeVal}"/>
</Style>
```

I want change `FontSizeVal` from Code Behind instead. I tried to use the below code, but it did not work (System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'):

```
App.Current.Resources["FontSizeVal"] = 10;
```

How can I set the `FontSizeVal` in code instead of in the XAML?

UPDATE:
my problem fixed, i changed :
10
to
10.0
tnx to @ash

Comment: "not work" doesn't explain *what happens*  in the program. does it throw runtime exception? or there is a TextBlock in UI and it still has same 12 fontsize? or smth else? please clarify

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Comment: `10` literal is interpreted as `int` here. try `10.0`

Comment: tnx this worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**summary**

`10` literal is interpreted as `int` here. use `10.0` which is `double`

---

here is some invetigation details

**Q**: what does `App.Current.Resources["FontSizeVal"] = 10;` do?

A: it replaces double resource with int resource. it is safe operation on its own

**Q**: why `InvalidCastException`?

A: due to DynamicResource behavior, TextBlock tries to apply `int` value resource to FontSize, but! FontSize expects `double`

if you try to set `int` value to FontSize via DP property

```
myTextBlock.SetValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, 10);
```

it throws "ArgumentException": 10 is not valid value for "FontSize" property.

setting double works!

```
myTextBlock.SetValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, 10.0);
```

and finally setting `int` via property wrapper:

```
myTextBlock.FontSize = 10;
```

it works because there is implicit cast from `int` to `double`.