# WPF - Change FontSize defined in App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

I set the FontSize properties in my App.xaml file like that :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
      ...
 </Style>
```

And so on for different control types.

What I want to do is give possibility to user to modify the fontsize, and so in code behind modify these values.
How can I modify that? Or is this possible to "bind" the values in my App.xaml to some of value in my ViewModel?

Comment: DynamicResource comes to resque: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47848017/1506454

Comment: @ASh thanks, in fact seems it's a duplicate (couldn't find it by myself...)

Comment: @Ash after some tries, cannot find where I am supposed to put '<System:Double x:Key="FontSizeVal">12</System:Double>', I am trying to insert in my '<Application.Resources>' section, but am getting errors. (The namespace prefix "System" is not defined), trying to replace "System" by my namespace, but no result

Comment: you need a xmlns for `System` namespace where Double is defined: `xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`